# How to dynamically add a canvas inside script tag to HTML using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have the following problem: I need to be able to add dynamically a canvas (to be precise, a specific canvas, like this one https://web.chemdoodle.com/tutorial/2d-structure-canvases/sketcher-canvas/) in .js file but my several attempts failed. I want to insert the canvas into `<div id="sketcher_canvas"></div>`.The canvas can be created inside script tag only, so I need to add script tags to HTML too. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ELN</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/main.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/main2.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- ChemDoodle -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='ChemDoodle/install/ChemDoodleWeb.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='ChemDoodle/install/ChemDoodleWeb.js')}}"></script>

    <!--these two are required by the SketcherCanvas plugin-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='ChemDoodle/install/uis/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='ChemDoodle/install/uis/ChemDoodleWeb-uis.js')}}"></script>
</head>

<body>        
      <script>    
          function make_canvas(){
            sketcher = new ChemDoodle.SketcherCanvas('sketcher',600,200);
          };
        </script>            

     <div id='sketcher_canvas'>

     </div>         

    <script        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my .js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // First option
    $('sketcher_canvas').append('<script>make_canvas();<\/script>);

    // Second option     
    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    script.text  = "make_canvas()";
    var div = document.getElementById('sketcher_canvas');
    div.innerHTML = script.text;
});
```

Any comments/suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, but you have a typo in your js file. There is a missing single quote after script.

Comment: You should use `</script>` instead of `<\/script>` to close the tag in the first option. Both options will generate multiple canvases with the same `id` thought. You're also including jQuery twice

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making things more complicated than they need to be.  You don't need to make a new script to call a function from another script.  You can call that function with a button like so:

```
        <script>    
          function make_canvas(){
             var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
             newCanvas.id = "sketcher";
             newCanvas.class = "ChemDoodleWebComponent";
             document.getElementById("sketcher_canvas").appendChild(newCanvas);
            sketcher = new ChemDoodle.SketcherCanvas('sketcher',600,200);
          };
        </script>            
     <button onclick="make_canvas()">Make Canvas</button>
     <div id='sketcher_canvas'>

     </div>
```

**EDIT:** I have updated the make_canvas function.  You can see how it works in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/tjkmv7bw/).

Comment: Will 'Make Canvas' button create a canvas inside the div?I doubt. Canvas can be generated inside the script tag. I need a controlled way to dynamically create several canvases in different parts of the web page.

Comment: If you need to add canvases to different elements on the page, you could pass through the element id as a parameter of the make_canvas function.  Then it would be `document.getElementById(id).appendChild(newCanvas);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts! Unfortunately only toolbar is loading. I will contact the authors of the library to find out what is happening.